# Is there a "more functional" way to handle both arms of a Result which call simple functions in Rust?

Tags: rust, unwrap

I often find myself writing code that, in human language reads like "*if the method call is OK, call this function, else, call that function*".

In code:

```
match client.favourite(&status.id) {
  Ok(_) => info!("Favourited {}", &status.id),
  Err(err) => error!("Could not favourite {}: {:#?}", &status.id, err),
};
```

Here, I'm merely calling a macro that logs to stdout, which could probably be abstracted away. The question is not whether this exact case can be improved, I'm looking if it is *more Rust-ish* to write this differently, or whether this is considered *The Best Way* already.

E.g. I could imagine something like:

```
client.favourite(&status.id)
  .on_ok(|_| info!("Favourited {}", &status.id))
  .on_err(|err| error!("Could not favourite {}: {:#?}", &status.id, err))
```

But I don't see such methods in the std-lib. But maybe I'm reading them wrong, maybe one of the `unwrap_or_*` does allow such usages?

Am I trying to do something un-rust-ish, and is the match/branch really the common way, or are there methods on `Result` that I'm overlooking, or usages that I am missing?

Comment: `on_ok` is more or less [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map) and `on_err` is more or less [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err)

Answer (score 3):

You have `map` and `map_err` which can be used for that:

```rust
use tracing::{error, info}; // 0.1.36

fn main() {
    let status_id = 123;
    Ok("foo")
        .map(|v| {
            info!("Favourited {}", &status_id);
            v
        })
        .map_err(|err: String| {
            error!("Could not favourite {}: {:#?}", &status_id, err);
            err
        });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb5ff40a278de053afedfbc6507311d2)

Comment: When I implement that, I get a `warning: unused \`Result\` that must be used`, which the example at the playground does too. This makes sense, because the `map_err` and `map` return a result. Both `map` and `map_err` don't signify that they handle the result, instead they signify that they change it. Yet I'd be using them as if they do handle the Result.

Comment: @berkes, well, I dont really knew if you need the result or not. You could either discard it with `_ = res.map(..).map_err(..)`, or use the match.

Comment: @netweave: you did put me on the right path though: Turns out `map_or_else` comes closest: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=285a7aa1d504b059fe531767d48681ca Thanks to a twitter-user as well: https://mobile.twitter.com/fusillicode/status/1566716705405018113

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I just realized that I re-implemented [`Result::map_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_or_else). So use that one instead.

Although I'd still argue that the original `match` construct should be the way to go, because it's widely accepted and used, concise and very Rusty.

---

-- original answer --

I think this is considered the best way already.

Yes, you could use `map()` and `map_err()`, but they are meant for *modifying* the result, not for *consuming* it. You still have to do something with it in the end.

But If you want `Result` to have different functionality, you are in luck ;) Rust allows you to add functionality to an existing type.

For example, I added the `resolve` method to `Result` here, which does kind of what you want:

```rust
// Boilerplate code to get the example to work in the first place
struct Client {
    should_succeed: bool,
}

impl Client {
    fn favourite(&self, id: &mut u32) -> Result<(), String> {
        *id = 42;
        if self.should_succeed {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err("Things went horribly wrong.".into())
        }
    }
}

// Custom functionality for Result
trait ResolveResult<T, E> {
    fn resolve(self, on_ok: impl FnOnce(T), on_err: impl FnOnce(E));
}

impl<T, E> ResolveResult<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn resolve(self, on_ok: impl FnOnce(T), on_err: impl FnOnce(E)) {
        match self {
            Ok(v) => on_ok(v),
            Err(e) => on_err(e),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut status_id: u32 = 0;
    let client = Client {
        should_succeed: false,
    };

    client.favourite(&mut status_id).resolve(
        |()| println!("Favourited {}", &status_id),
        |err| println!("Could not favourite {}: {:#?}", &status_id, err),
    );
}
```

```
Could not favourite 42: "Things went horribly wrong."
```

Although I would still argue that I'd use the `match` construct instead. It's also four lines, it's concise, and after you get used to Rust a little, it reads just as easily.